# How to stop a broadcast receiver from itself?

Tags: android

I have a `BroadcastReceiver` that will run on the background regardless of my application lifecycle. This `BroadcastReceiver` is initiated on the `manifest` and launched by a `PendingIntent`.

I need to stop this `BroadcastReceiver` at some point, and i must do it inside the `BroadcastReceiver` it self (inside `onReceive` perhaps?).

I tried to call `abortBroadcast()` but no luck, the `BroadcastReceiver` is still getting called again and again.

Please kindly help me, Thanks a lot for your help

UPDATE

This is how i launch the `BroadcastReceiver` :

```
Intent intent = new Intent("mypackage.ACTION_RECEIVE_GEOFENCE");
        intent.putExtra("toStation", Constants.toStation);
        PendingIntent geofencePendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        LocationServices.GeofencingApi.addGeofences(
                mGoogleApiClient,
                getGeofencingRequest(),
                geofencePendingIntent
        ).setResultCallback(this);
```

And this is on my `manifest` :

```
<receiver android:name="mypackage.GeofenceUpdateReceiver"
            android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter >
                <action android:name="mypackage.ACTION_RECEIVE_GEOFENCE"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

I use Google's `Geofence API`

Comment: What do you mean, exactly? The BroadcastReceiver will stop running at the end of the `onReceive()` method.

Comment: Thanks for helping. But `BroadcastReceiver` keeps getting called even after `onReceive` finished. Or should i stop the PendingIntent instead? But is it possible to stop the  `PendingIntent` from the `BroadcastReceiver`?

Comment: Where's the PendingIntent coming from? Are you setting an alarm?

Comment: The `PendingIntent ` coming from an `Activity`. No, i dont use `AlarmManager`

Comment: Please post the relevant code.

Comment: What are the transition types you're setting on the GeoFence(s)? If you've got `GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_DWELL` set, I'd imagine that's why it keeps firing. If you need the dwell type, and it's firing more often than you like, you can change the delay.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96844/discussion-between-blaze-tama-and-mike-m).